# Como executar um método do Bean ao clicar no botão Save do rich:Editor usando RichFaces4?

Tags: java, jsf

Olá,

Estou usando o RichFaces4 e em meu projeto inclui a tag 
Este apresenta um botao Save (Disket) e minha intenção é chamar um método no meu Bean e executar meu código para salvar.
   Não quero adicionar um novo botão, pois gostaria de seguir o padrão das aplicações em que meus usuários estão mais familiarizados.

Fiz já essa pergunta na versão em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923187/how-to-custom-the-save-button-on-editor-using-richfaces-4

O código de meu Bean e xhtml seguem a baixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
<http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>


   <h:form>


<rich:editor id="editor" toolbar="full" value="#{editorBean.value}"
    style="margin-bottom: 1em" height="400" >


    <a4j:ajax event="change" render="panel"  status="panelUpdateStatus" />

    <a4j:ajax event="dirty" render="panel" status="panelUpdateStatus">
        <a4j:attachQueue requestDelay="1000" />
    </a4j:ajax>



</rich:editor>

<rich:panel id="panel">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Output from Editor
        <a4j:status name="panelUpdateStatus">
            <f:facet name="start">
                (Updating)
            </f:facet>
        </a4j:status>
    </f:facet>
        <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{editorBean.value}" />

</rich:panel>
```

Bean

```
 import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
 import javax.inject.Named;

  @Named
  @SessionScoped
  public class EditorBean implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5383915229820571701L;


  private String value;

  /** 
  * @return the value
  */
   public String getValue() {
       return value;
   }

  /**
  * @param value the value to set
  */
   public void setValue(String value) {
      this.value = value;
   } 

   public void save(){
       System.out.println(" Saving ");
      //Code to save
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O component `rich:editor` não dispara nenhum evento do JSF ao clicar no botão de save (o disquete), no entanto, é possível fazer a seguinte gambiarra:

- Adicionar um botão `a4j:commandButton` invisível que dispara o método `save()` do seu EditorBean;
- Capturar o evento de click no botão save do editor e via javascript, disparar o evento click() do botão invisível.

Uma outra alternativa mais fácil e mais elegante é implementar um auto-save, para essa solução, basta ter presente um `<a4j:ajax event="change" />` dentro do seu editor que ele vai automaticamente chamar o método `setValue(String value)` do seu EditorBean, então basta modificar a lógica desse método para que ele persista o valor recebido.

Documentação do componente `rich:editor`: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/nightly_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Rich_inputs.html#sect-Component_Reference-Rich_inputs-richeditor

Pergunta sobre como capturar o evento no botão save do CKEditor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330796/how-to-capture-click-event-on-save-button-of-ckeditor